# How to Concatenate rows linked to single ID using group by?

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a script to create a table that will concatenate the data from the table having the same ID. The output should be as follows: "IF DSW7841_gUDT.sOpState = 1 OR DSW7842_gUDT.sOpState = 1 OR DSW8841_gUDT.sOpState = 1  THEN GLB084.ModuleInOut.mDoorOpen := 1; ELSE GLB084.ModuleInOut.mDoorOpen := 0; END_IF;"

The script that i have written is like this:

```
begin
create table if not exists public.opstate_mappings (
id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
    door_switch_opstate_id uuid references door_switch_opstate(id) on delete cascade,
    opstate_mapping text not null unique
);
insert into opstate_mapping(door_switch_opstate_id, opstate_mapping)
select door_switch_opstate.software_instance_id,
GROUP_CONCAT('IF',door_switch_opstate.door_switches,'_gUDT.sOpState = 1 OR') AS opstate_mapping
FROM door_switch_opstate
GROUP BY software_instance_id;
end;
```

[This is the table i am extracting data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCwAv.png) EDIT: THIS PICTURE SHOWS ONLY ONE ID THAT IS LINKED WITH ALL THE DOOR_SWITCHES, THERE ARE OTHER MORE ID'S LINKED WITH OTHER ROWS

Comment: You've tagged 3 different products... which one are you actually using?

Comment: i am using postgresql

Comment: If you [edit] your question and remove the other tags please.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres the command you seek is STRING_AGG and would go something like this:

```
  CONCAT('IF ', 
    STRING_AGG(door_switch_opstate.door_switches, '_gUDT.sOpState = 1 OR'), 
    '_gUDT.sOpState = 1 THEN GLB084.ModuleInOut.mDoorOpen := 1; ELSE GLB084.ModuleInOut.mDoorOpen := 0; END_IF;'
  )
```